# Long running backend process giving 504 gateway timeout error. SpringBoot backend, AWS EKS Ingress

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, http-status-code-504

I am facing a problem where my backend application is doing some complex calculation and due to which its taking more more than 2 minutes to complete and I am constantly getting 504 gateway timeout.

When I check the logs using pod logs `watch` command, I can see that the process is running smoothly and its finished its task without any error.

Please help to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

My backend application (SprintBoot app) was performing some complex calculation and I was getting ***504 Gateway Timeout***, while the calculation was performing its work at the backend.

After investing the issue, I found out that this problem is related to `idle timeout duration` annotation in the kubernetes ingress configuration. My timeout was set to *120 seconds* which wasn't enough for calculation and the calculation was taking more time to complete.

To resolve this issue, I updated the following annotation in the ingress.
`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=300`.

To update in Windows, I performed the following steps:

1. kubectl get ingress (Get the current ingress)

```
PS C:\aks> kubectl get ingress -n my-namespace
NAME       CLASS  HOSTS ADDRESS        PORTS  AGE
my-ingress <none>   *    52.152.91.154  80    10m
```

2. Edit the ingress configuration using `edit` command
   `kubectl edit ingress my-ingress -n my-namespace` (It will open a new file in a notepad)

```
PS C:\aks> kubectl edit ingress my-ingress -n my-namespace
ingress.networking.k8s.io/my-ingress edited
```

In the notepad , you can go-ahead and modify the service name and save it.
Once you see this message `ingress.networking.k8s.io/my-ingress edited`, this means the changes have been applied.

I took help from following articles and wanna share here for the readers

- https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-http-504-errors
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1031687/how-to-edit-an-existing-ingress-nginx-rule-in-azur ( This is Azure example but its applicable for EKS and GKE also)